# Set variable on the same line as command

Tags: shell, sh, csh

In sh programming I can do this:

```
dryrun="echo " ./myscript.sh
```

And script uses it as:

```
${dryrun}ls -l (as an example)
```

I can't seem to figure out how to call script in csh with the same effect.

Comment: I'm using mostly bash, so I can't tell for sure with sh, even less csh. For bash, I'd use *dryrun="echo "**;** ./myscript.sh* (note the semicolon) and a blank between ${dryrun} and ls.

Comment: Your solution with the semicolon is doing something fundamentally different.  Sergei is setting an *environment* variable that will be visible to the subsequent command.  Your solution is setting a *shell local variable* that will not be available within `myscript.sh`.

Comment: @larsks Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easy solution is to use the `env` command:

```
env dryrun=echo ./myscript.sh
```

This will work with pretty much any shell.  The `env` command takes a list of `var=value` pairs and adds them to the environment of whatever command is at the end of the list.  See `man env` for more information.

Comment: I tested under csh and bash and both work.   Thanks.